# Error while working with delegate in swift

Tags: swift, delegates, protocols, xcode11, unwrap

I am working in XCode 11 and I am trying to use a delegate in my code. However, it gives me an error: **Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value**

I've worked with protocols and delegates before and I have never encountered this problem. Can someone please help me to figure out what might be the issue? Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```
class RedScreenVC: UIViewController {

    var delegate: NavDelegate!

    var redView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height))

    var navigateButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 200, y: 350, width: 150, height: 50))
        button.setTitle("Navigate", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.backgroundColor = .blue
        return button
    }()

    @objc func buttonAction(){
        if self.redView.backgroundColor == .gray {
            self.redView.backgroundColor = .systemPink
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        navigateButton.layer.cornerRadius = 25
        redView.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray

        delegate.navigate(text: "Navigation Success", isShown: true)

        view.addSubview(redView)

        view.addSubview(navigateButton)
    }
}
```

And here is the protocol for the delegate which I've created:

```
protocol NavDelegate {
    func navigate(text: String, isShown: Bool)
}
```

Comment: kindly add presenting code of RedScreenVC.

Comment: Make navigateButton lazy `lazy var navigateButton: UIButton =`. As it is your code `addTarget(self,` runs when there is no self

Comment: Where do you create the delegate? May be the delegate is an empty so you see the error. And you should use optional values and avoid of using force unwrapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to to assign delegate value from prepare function. Or you can assign delegate with initialize RedScreenVC(self) from your ViewController if u don't want to use storyboard/xib.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, NavDelegate {
    func navigate(text: String, isShown: Bool) {
        print("text: \(text) isShown: \(isShown)")
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        let common = SHService()
        common.printMe(printString: "Hello World")
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if (segue.identifier == "RedScreenVC") {
            let RedScreenVC = segue.destination as? RedScreenVC
            RedScreenVC?.delegate = self
        }
    }

    @IBAction func nextPageButtonEventLustener(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "RedScreenVC", sender: sender)
    }
}



import UIKit

protocol NavDelegate {
    func navigate(text: String, isShown: Bool)
}
class RedScreenVC: UIViewController {

     weak var delegate: NavDelegate?

    var redView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height))

    var navigateButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 200, y: 350, width: 150, height: 50))
        button.setTitle("Navigate", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.backgroundColor = .blue
        return button
    }()

    @objc func buttonAction(){
        if self.redView.backgroundColor == .gray {
            self.redView.backgroundColor = .systemPink
        }
      self.delegate.navigate(text:"", isShown: true)

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        navigateButton.layer.cornerRadius = 25
        redView.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray

        delegate.navigate(text: "Navigation Success", isShown: true)

        view.addSubview(redView)

        view.addSubview(navigateButton)
    }

}
```